# How to create vcard with own datas in Java?

Tags: java, vcf-vcard

I'm doing a phonebook and I'd like to save contacts to vcard. I found vcard format on the internet, but I do not know how to read datas from stdin.

```
package homework;

import java.io.*;

public class SaveToVcard {

    public static void vcard() throws IOException {
        File file = new File("contact.vcf");
        FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(file);

        if (file.exists()) {
            String vcard = "BEGIN:VCARD\n" + "VERSION:4.0\n" + "N:Gump;Forrest;;;\n" + "FN:Forrest Gump\n"
                    + "ORG:Bubba Gump Shrimp Co.\n" + "TITLE:Shrimp Man\n"
                    + "TEL;TYPE=work,voice;VALUE=uri:tel:+1-111-555-1212\n"
                    + "TEL;TYPE=home,voice;VALUE=uri:tel:+1-404-555-1212\n" + "EMAIL:forrestgump@example.com\n"
                    + "REV:20080424T195243Z\n" + "END:VCARD";
            fop.write(vcard.getBytes());

            BufferedReader br = null;
            String currentLine;
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("contact.vcf"));
            while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(currentLine);
            }

            fop.flush();
            fop.close();
            System.out.println("Kész");
        } else
            System.out.println("A fájl nem létezik");

    }
```

Comment: What you want is to upload the generated file from the console? Or actually read from stdin or from some parameter to create a vcard?

Comment: Sorry for the inaccuracy,yes, I would like to do this.

Comment: Just a nitpick, but the RFC 6350 for vCard states that the line break should be CRLF "\r\n".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Scanner and do something like this

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = sc.next();
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Or maybe you can pass what you need as parameters when running your application

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

Comment: Thank you for your help, I used what you said and applied String.format